# sforce.connection.query is undefined

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, soap

I'm trying to use the soap/apex toolkit for my organization and it keeps crashing when I try to query for objects.

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jq$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq$(document).ready(function() {                         
        try{
            var qr = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Name From account");
            alert('I am here');
            var records = qr.getArray("records");
            alert(records.length);
         }
        catch(err){
            alert(err.message);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before using sforce.connection.query, session ID should be set. Try below code,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jq$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq$(document).ready(function() {                         
        try{
            sforce.connection.sessionId = ‘{!$Api.Session_ID}’;
            var qr = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Name From account");
            alert('I am here');
            var records = qr.getArray("records");
            alert(records.length);
         }
        catch(err){
            alert(err.message);
        }
    });
</script>
```